# How do I trim a string to parse a time with a SimpleDateFormat in java?

Tags: java, string, time, datetime-parsing

I'm trying to input a string with a mix of characters and have some bit of code remove all but the part that matches the desired SimpleDateFormat

```
String wholeString = new String("The time is 7:00.");
String timeOnlyString = CODE TO TRIM STRING;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date timeAsObject = sdf.parse(timeOnlyString);
String timeAsString = sdf.format(timeAsObject);
System.out.println(timeAsString);`
```

With this code I'd like

> 07:00

Printed in the console.

Comment: Use regular expressions or if the wholeString is constant width use substring,

Comment: Assuming `CODE TO TRIM STRING` actually returns _7:00_, your code works for me. It prints _07:00_ to the console. What is your actual problem? Does your code throw an exception? Does it not print _07:00_ to the console?

Comment: `CODE TO TRIM STRING` should return 7:00, but I have no clue what code to put in there to actually make it do that. I just put it as a proxy to fill the example code.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your time work.

```
    String wholeString = "The time is 7:00.";
    Matcher m = TIME_PATTERN.matcher(wholeString);
    while (m.find()) {
        String timeOnlyString = m.group();
        try {
            LocalTime timeAsObject
                    = LocalTime.parse(timeOnlyString, TIME_FORMATTER);
            System.out.println("Time found: " + timeAsObject);
        } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
            System.out.println("Looked a bit like a time but couldn’t be parsed as one: " + timeOnlyString);
        }
    }
```

I used these two static declarations:

```
private static final Pattern TIME_PATTERN
        = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}\\b");
private static final DateTimeFormatter TIME_FORMATTER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm");
```

Output from my snippet is:

> Time found: 07:00

The regular expression that I use for extracting the time from the whole string matches 1 or 2 digits, a colon and 2 digits. It requires a word boundary before and after so we don’t happen to extract a time from `987:12354` or `letters1:11moreletters`.

The format pattern string used for the `DateTimeFormatter` has just one `H` for hour of day. This accepts 1 or 2 digits, so we can parse `15:00` too.

I think that we should take into account that the regex may match more than once in the string, so I am extracting in a loop.

I am parsing in to `java.time.LocalTime`. This class is for a time of day (from 00:00 through 23:59:59.999999999), so suits your need much better than the outdated `Date` class (which represents neither a date nor a time of day, but a point in time without time zone).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the regex, `.*?(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}(?:\:\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,9})?)?).*` to match the whole string and replace it with the pattern matched by group#1.

**Description of the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/PtFhju/1):**

- `.*?` : Matches (lazily) any character any number of times
- `(`: Start of capturing group#1

  - `\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}` : One to two digits followed by one to two digits
  - `(?:` : Start of the optional non-capturing group

    - `\:\d{1,2}` : `:` followed by one to two digits (for seconds)

      - `(?:` : Start of the optional non-capturing group

        - `\.\d{1,9}` : `.` followed by one to nine digits (for nano seconds)
      - `)?` : Close of optional non-capturing group
  - `)?` : Close of optional non-capturing group
- `)` : Close of capturing group#1
- `.*`:  Matches any character any number of times

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test strings
        String[] wholeStringArr = { "The time is 7:00.", "The time is 7:00:05.", "The time is 7:00:05.1.",
                "The time is 7:00:05.123.", "The time is 7:00:05.123456789." };

        for (String wholeString : wholeStringArr) {
            String timeOnlyString = wholeString.replaceAll(".*?(\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}(?:\\:\\d{1,2}(?:\\.\\d{1,9})?)?).*",
                    "$1");
            System.out.println(timeOnlyString);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
7:00
7:00:05
7:00:05.1
7:00:05.123
7:00:05.123456789
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/Xdfpyr)

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String wholeString = "The time is 7:00.";
        String timeOnlyString = wholeString.replaceAll(".*?(\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}(?:\\:\\d{1,2}(?:\\.\\d{1,9})?)?).*",
                "$1");

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter
                .ofPattern("H:m[:s[.[SSSSSSSSS][SSSSSSSS][SSSSSSS][SSSSSS][SSSSS][SSSS][SSS][SS][S]", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(timeOnlyString, dtf);
        System.out.println(time);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
07:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/gKkPZr)

Notice the optional patterns in the square brackets.

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```java
String wholeString = "The time is 7:00.";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(0?[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(wholeString);
if(matcher.find()) {
    String timeOnlyString = matcher.group();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Date timeAsObject = sdf.parse(timeOnlyString);
    String timeAsString = sdf.format(timeAsObject);
    System.out.println(timeAsString);
}
```

Comment: It may help make the answer more clear if you explain that you are using a regular expression and how that expression works. Also, I think you should mention that, since Java 8, it is recommended **not** to use class `SimpleDateFormat`.